# ASP.NET MVC and SSRS 2008 R2 ReportViewer (Control)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

Dear all,
I have to use the report viewer control within a MVC 3 application and have problems to realize this by using a webforms page. Each time I call my reports via a report list view
I have got an error that the resource cannot be found. I know that this is caused by a wrong route mapping which must be set in the global asax file. How should I define the route to solve this issue?
Here is the virtual path of my report list view:
http://servername/reports/
After selecting a report it should be possible to call the report webforms page via a link
(the virtual path looks like this: http://servername/reports/reportname).
Can anyone help me?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following ignore routes to your route definitions:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("reports");
routes.IgnoreRoute("reports/{*pathInfo}");
```